# Android actual auto-scaling width/height parameters?

Tags: android, xml, height, width, density-independent-pixel

I was under the impression that 'dip' (Density Independent Pixel) values were the android solution to using % values to determine the width and height of layout elements. I thought this was an upgrade to using static 'px' (pixel) values or other static measurements like centimeter or inch.

Unfortunately dip values do not scale like a percentage value would, is there anything like percentage values with width and height parameters in Android?

Insight appreciated!

Comment: Could you give an example, what you want to do? - something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
 android:layout_weight=".70"
```

So that would be 70% of the space.

You would just add it to whichever value you want, like a button or textbox or something

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't accept floats"?  I'm working on a project now that has "android:layout_weight=".5" in the layout for a button, and the button takes exactly 50% of the view.

Comment: you're wrong! it accepts floats, not sure until which digit after the coma, but at least the first digit after the coma is accepted!

Comment: `error: Error: Float types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value '.7').`  Did this on a linearlayout right now in the XML file, that is what the error said, and I am using Android 3.0 for this tablet only app

Comment: How is the -1? Even is this is something that cant be used on Android 3.0, you never specified that you where using that in the question....

Comment: from my understanding, even deprecated functions are forward compatible so far, so I didn't feel that I needed to specify. Can you post a working XML example using those floats values?

Comment: I'd just like to specify that your error posted above says "layout_width" and they're saying use "layout_weight" .. similar, but not the same.  :)  That could be why you're getting an error.

Comment: thanks, I definitely did not notice that! everyone should rank him up

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to do this is programmatically **or by using layout_weight**

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541246/android-fill-percent-of-layout) for info on layout_weight

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I didn't realize layout_weight was accompanied by layout_sum in the parent node

Answer (score 0):

I had that same issue, but could not find an answer, so I switched to doing everything progmatically instead of within XML..  That's the only insight I can offer you.  :P  Sorry!  In response to the other answer .. I never tried layout_weight..  Only layout_width and layout_height..  But if you're trying layout_weight and it doesn't accept floats, it might be a different ADK level.  (I'm programming on ADK 7)

Comment: I'm using Android 3.0 so there shouldn't really be any limitations with known Android issues at this point